# paper.js: getting raw pixel data for two layers/groups?

Tags: javascript, genetic-algorithm, paperjs

I am trying to get the raw pixel data from two "items" in paper.js. One is already a Raster object so that's not too bad. The problem is that I have another `Group` object containing a bunch of triangles and I want to capture the `Raster` data for that layer and then be able to compare it.

I have the following (highlighted lines) code:
https://gist.github.com/mtahmed/2b27c4c6aee42d3ac3fb#file-paper_update-js

It seems to always return 0 or some other odd unexpected number. Any hints/ideas?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are always setting `child_gene.visible = false`, but never set it back to `visible = true` before you rasterize the layer in `computeFitness()`.  I'm not sure that there's a need for juggling layers in each frame - it should work just as well without it.

[Here's a simplified example that uses a square with a gradient as the target raster.](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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)

Comment: Oh one needs to make the group visible before I rasterize it?

Comment: In your `onFrame` function, try: `child_gene.visible=true; fitness=computeFitness(child_gene, target)`. Since `rasterize()` does not change the original object, there's no need to pass a new layer

Comment: Didn't seem to work :(
I tried and "simplified" it so only mutation happens ... still doesn't seem to work. Here's the updated code: https://gist.github.com/mtahmed/2b27c4c6aee42d3ac3fb#file-paper_update-js

Comment: It'd be easier to give you pointers with a complete example. I've edited the answer with a simplified version that runs on sketch.paperjs.org